# Programmatically created user is active?

Tags: django-users

Django 1.9.6

I just want to test if anonymous user is redirected to login page.
I've created some user. It is definitely not registered.

Could you help me understand, why its property is_active is set to True.
Well, I stopped at pdb breakpoint and:

```
-> pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) request.user.is_active
True
```

I have to explicitly set user.is_active = False. But why is the user active by default is a mystery to me. Nobody has activated it, I would say.

The code is below.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .views import HomePageView
from django.http.request import HttpRequest
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class GeneralTest(TestCase):

    def test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page(self):
        user = User(username='anonymous', email='vvv@mail.ru', password='ttrrttrr')        
        request = HttpRequest()
        request.user = user
        hpv = HomePageView()
        response = hpv.get(request)
        pdb.set_trace()
```